# How can I scale a subset of my game view during rendering?

Tags: textures, sdl, scale

I am developing a 2d game which has a lateral panel and a main panel with the scenario. I want to scale the main scenario to apply a zoom (only the main panel portion of the screen).

I think if I use `SDL_SetRenderTarget` I will be able to change textures and then zoom it, in runtime. I have to use only SDL2 library or some extension. I can't use openGL.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is frame buffer. https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is render to a texture (via render targets) and then draw the texture to the screen. Then take a portion of the texture and render it with in a rectangle somewhere on screen. (SDL_RenderCopy lets you only draw a portion of the texture)